# Gracefully Degrading ContentEditable on iPhone & iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, contenteditable, graceful-degradation

To my dismay, I found out that the `contentEditable=true` attribute does not work as expected on iPhones or iPads.

Is there a way to gracefully degrade a contentEditable div without resorting to a textarea and losing all of the rich DHTML formatting benefits on an iPhone or iPad?

Comment: I would also like to see a solution for this for other non-html5 browsers (IE for instance)

Comment: @pate: You should switch the Accept to tim's answer - iOS now supports `contenteditable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contenteditable` is supported from IOS 5 onward

Go here on your iPad to try it out

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have gone through this(**Apple's Technical Notes**) and **Safari Web Content Guide** they put following paragraph under **Don’t Use Unsupported iOS Technologies**

`contenteditable` is not supported in Safari on iPhone OS. If you're using `contenteditable` to enable text input within a styled element (for instance, `<p contenteditable>` or `<div contentediable>`), **you can replace this styled element with a styled <`textarea`>**. In Safari on iPad, iPhone, Mac OS X, and Windows, you can customize the appearance of `<textarea>` elements using **CSS**. If necessary, you can even disable any platform-specific, built-in styling on a `<textarea>` by specifying `-webkit-appearance: none`.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't really know how I'd go about implementing that.. how to get the styles from the text area, etc.

Comment: good point, any realization so far? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788007/workaround-for-contenteditable-on-ipad